# Show toggle div with anchor url

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, toggle, anchor

I am using the following script to open/close a div on my webpage;

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $(".showA").hide();
     $(".show_hideB").show();

     $('.show_hideB').click(function(){
     $(".showA").slideToggle();

     });

});
```

Everything works great but the problem is that I can't get it to work that when I surf to www.websitelink.com/#A to (toggle) open the anchor div #A automatic

I already tried the following, that I found here but that didnt helped me out:

```
if(document.location.hash) {
$('.' + document.location.hash.substring(1)).slideDown(); }
```

**note:** I am using the toggle javascript in more ways so i'm searching for a general solution and not only specific for the #A div (for example; if the url says: www.websitelink.com#c it should open #c ect. ect.)

I hope someone of you has a solution for me!
A big thank you in advanced!

Comment: I don't see an issue with your code, assuming you have an element on your page with a CSS class name corresponding with the supplied `document.location.hash` and your code starting `if(document.location.hash)` is called after the document has loaded (e.g. within `$(document).ready` function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `.` in the selector, it should be `#`:

```
if(document.location.hash) {
    $('#' + document.location.hash.substring(1)).slideDown();
}
```

Or, since `document.location.hash` always begins with `#`, you don't need the substring:

```
if(document.location.hash) {
    $(document.location.hash).slideDown();
}
```